# Why do my Cassandra hints files keep getting corrupted

Tags: java, cassandra, kubernetes

We're running multiple Kubernetes clusters, which run Cassandra.
Our usual procedure when doing a rolling restart of the Cassandra pods is to log into each and submit a `nodetool drain` and then trigger a recreation of that pod. But often when the pods restart we get errors like

```
ERROR [HintsDispatcher:2] 2017-08-07 11:09:32,489 HintsDispatchExecutor.java:243 - Failed to dispatch hints file 5fdd139d-4465-4825-85ef-f380bddcb67d-1502100535128-1.hints: file is corrupted ({})
```

Those corrupt files prevent Cassandra from starting. Is there a way to tell Cassandra to flush all buffers and stop writing, before stopping it, to ensure there are no corrupt files left behind?

Comment: include C* version please

Comment: You can simply make sure cassandra is fully stopped on the node, delete the corrupted hint file (along with its .crc32 file if it exists) and start cassandra again. If it stops on an other corrupted hint, repeat the process. I had to deal with several corrupted hint files recently after a major network problem between DCs which filled the hint filesystem on several servers. The latest hints that were being written when disk got full were corrupted. Ref: https://support.datastax.com/s/article/DSE-startup-fails-with-Failed-to-dispatch-hints-file-file-is-corrupted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to disable hinted handoff, or try to truncate hints after the drain:

**nodetool truncatehints**

If you care about consistency, run repair after the process.

**Warning:** If you are working with ANY consistency setting or RF=1, this may lead to some data loss.

Comment: There are possible scenarios that this could lead to inconsistencies or in some worst case scenarios data loss,

Comment: You are right about inconsistency. About data loss, first, depends on consistency settings and what is done with the cluster. If you are running in quorum with rf >=3 and doing rolling restart with draining the nodes, data loss is near impossible Second, on running cluster data loss due to hinted handoff disabled is possible only if working with "ANY" consistency, and not a recommended way to work with Cassandra.

Comment: your right that it shouldnt, but without knowing their version/usecase it is worst case possible. Deleting things like hints and commitlogs should be thought out throughly with individual use cases. I wanted to hear version they using but upgrading with the fix (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12728) _may_ be safer.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the answer with warning that this solution can lead to data loss  under some circumstances.